# How to get saved contact email in android?

Tags: java, android, email, contacts

I am trying to get the email of the saved contact name. but with my code, i could only select the name of the person. Now what i need is, get the email of the selected person and store in another editText. How to achieve it? Any help is really appreciated and thanks in advance... My code goes here...

```
@Override  
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {  
        switch (requestCode) {  
        case PICK_CONTACT:

            final EditText phoneInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.person);
            Cursor cursor = null;  
            String phoneNumber = "";
            String Name = "";
            List<String> allNumbers = new ArrayList<String>();
            int phoneIdx = 0;
            try {  
                Uri result = data.getData();  
                String id = result.getLastPathSegment();  
                cursor = getContentResolver().query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, Phone.CONTACT_ID + "=?", new String[] { id }, null);  
                phoneIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    while (cursor.isAfterLast() == false) {
                        phoneNumber = cursor.getString(phoneIdx);
                        allNumbers.add(phoneNumber);
                        cursor.moveToNext();
                    }
                } else {
                    //no results actions
                }  
            } catch (Exception e) {  
               //error actions
            } finally {  
                if (cursor != null) {  
                    cursor.close();
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case for 2.2 froyo this works,

```
Cursor emails = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI,null,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = " + contactId,null, null); 
   while (emails.moveToNext())         
   {         
      emailAddress = emails.getString(emails.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
    }        
   emails.close();
```

For more info please look at [Working With Android Contacts](http://www.higherpass.com/Android/Tutorials/Working-With-Android-Contacts/)